# PYINSTALLER FAILED TO EXECUTE SCRIPT (used pynput)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pynput

Recently, I have installed `pyinstaller 4.2.`

This is the error I get after running the script from cmd:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "Keylogger.py", line 1, in <module>

File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 359, in exec_module

File "pynput\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>

File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 359, in exec_module

File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.py", line 31, in <module>

File "pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 76, in backend

ImportError

[41576] Failed to execute script Keylogger
```

The command I used to convert to `.exe` is **"pyinstaller --onefile Keylogger.exe"**

I am a beginner coder so I don't understand what the error actually is. Can anyone pls help me? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you yelling?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the below command.

```
pyinstaller --onefile Keylogger.py
```

Your python file ends with .py extension.